# Access Realm object from services for execiting transaction

Tags: java, android

I have a background service in my Android app which should notify users 1 day before a specific date attribute in my database in the app. I know how to execute transaction and notify user but I am not able to access the realm object from service.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm provides a way to access your instance from anywhere.

```
// Create a RealmConfiguration that saves the Realm file in the app's "files" directory. 
//(Recommended to add this code in your Application or first Activity)
 RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
 Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);

//then call it from your service
 Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);

 //access your realm object
 realm.beginTransaction();
 final Dog managedDog = realm.copyToRealm(dog); // Persist unmanaged objects
 Person person = realm.createObject(Person.class); // Create managed objects directly
 person.getDogs().add(managedDog);
 realm.commitTransaction();
```

[see docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started)

Comment: Thank you so much it did work.

Comment: No problem, great!